# Change django picture img src in template based on min-width

Tags: django

I wasn't sure how to ask this question. Want to send correctly sized images to different screens from my django application. I have it so that when an image is uploaded, that it is saved to media but with multiple sizes.

[image: media]

So, the image above shows in my media/uploads/pieces/{ID}/Sargent.jpg and all of it's other sized images. The models imageField is pointing to the "original" file without an underscore and width.

**templates/art/piece_detail.html**

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width:300px)" srcset="{{ piece.image.url ??? }}">
    <source media="(min-width:375px)" srcset="{{ piece.image.url ??? }}">
    <source media="(min-width:786px)" srcset="{{ piece.image.url ??? }}">
    <source media="(min-width:1440px)" srcset="{{ piece.image.url ??? }}">
    <img src="{{ piece.image.url }}" alt="{{ piece.name }} - {{ piece.height }} x {{ piece.width }}">
</picture>
```

Then here I am using an HTML `<picture>` tag with some source medias to be how I serve the appropriate image. However I am at a loss on maybe the best way to do what I am trying to accomplish. I realize these break points are probably not exactly what I need, but just trying to get my idea across.

I thought about adding more "path" fields to the Piece model and set them to these other URL paths too, but that seems like a sloppy solution to this. Otherwise, I think I would need to do some string manipulation in the view before it gets to the template...

Additionally what are today's standard image break points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

that accepts the image url and specific width and return the URL with the width plugged in.

```
def format_img_src(img_ur, size):
    """Returns an image of specific size"""
    # do your formatting here
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar sir! Thank you so much. This was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
class my_model_name(models.Model):
    ......
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to = '')

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(my_model_name, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height>300 or img.width > 300:
        img.thumbnail( (300,300) )
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

If you use this `save` mathod than your all img save 300*300.you can chane your size .